# react-navigation/native could not be found within the project or in these directories: node_modules

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I already check my `package-lock.json`, I already add the dependencies but this error just keep coming and I don't know what to do.

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gBN9.png):

```
//make this component available to the app
export default NavigationContainer(navigator);
```

Thats my `app.js` code and this is my JSON:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/core": "^3.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.8",
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.2.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.2.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.11.1"
```

This is the error message:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sqQ5.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Run npm install, I had the same error, I do not know why but installing it for the first time did not work.

Comment: yes i tried npm install and its work really i dont know whats going on lol